# dll loaded from system32 instead of local folder

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I noticed some trouble with a dll in my software when deployed. I usually include all required 3rd party dlls in the folder of my executable. However, I noticed a dll not being found on some machines even though it is right there. On my development machine, I found out via [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) that the dll is taken in C:/windows/system32/. So from that I infer that on other machines it may be searched for in system32 directory and since it's not there, it's not loaded. I'd like to add that the dll is NOT a known dll, i.e. it is NOT present in the registry at `HKML\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs`. The library I'm talking about is in this case `kinect10.dll` and I link my code with `#pragma comment( lib, "kinect10.lib" )`. So my question is why is the local dll (the one next to the exe file) ignored in this case?

Comment: Check your EXE for a specified resource manifest or external manifest file; application manifests can override DLL search paths.  Also check the architecture (32-bit versus 64-bit) of your process and dependent modules; if the architecture of the DLL being placed in the application directory doesn't match the process' (EXE) architecture, the EXE will refuse to load it.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I accidentally had the 32bit dll locally (for my 64 bit exe), which caused it to be silently skipped. Instead, the correct one was then found in System32 on my development machine but not on the other.